# Audio Visualizer C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, naudio

I'm writing an audio visualizer in C#/Asp.net/JavaScript (as a website). Since my animations should move smoothly along with the music I thought it would make more sense to preprocess the MP3 in the code behind, write the values/frequencies to a text file or something, then use javascript to read the values and modify the animation accordingly. Basically I want to do something like this bar thing: https://lh4.ggpht.com/Qhm4EeDUgVlvLcX4MiZ1idGDUo5cD5PmLAIZIfnJlilzU789OPXAUK_emJSOT3CK4Vs=h900
I need some kind of number value to use as the height of the bars and it should change as the music continues.
I'm using Naudio for this. Here's my code:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using NAudio;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MP3toWAV(MapPath("~/Music/UctfnI6yUPM.mp3"), MapPath("~/Music/UctfnI6yUPM.wav"));
        Strip(MapPath("~/Music/UctfnI6yUPM.wav"));
    }
    public void MP3toWAV(string file,string output)
    {
        using (NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(file))
        {
            NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(output, reader);
        }
    }
    public void Strip(string path)
    {
        NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(path));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int read = 0;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(MapPath("~/Result.txt"));
        while (wave.Position < wave.Length)
        {
            read = wave.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);
            for (int i = 0; i < read / 4; i++)
            {
                writer.Write(BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, i * 4));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's part of the output on pastebin:http://pastebin.com/Ve5tym20
I couldn't copy the whole thing because it was a ~90mb text file.
I'm not quite sure how i'm supposed to use this data and whether or not this is the right data in the first place.
I have spent the past few days looking up how to do this. I have seen Mark Heath's article on autotune, and I have also looked at the BandedSpectrumAnalyzer project.I got a lot of my code from the article but the BandedSpectrumAnalyzer project was kind of confusing to me (i didnt know what part of it did what)
Help Please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to build an EQ visualization in the browser i would recommend using the WebAudio HTML5 API instead of your server-side approach. You can easily manipulate mp3 and other file types using the WebAudio api

You can find many examples online how to use the API. Some nice examples are listed here:
http://webaudio.github.io/demo-list/

The API is currently supported only in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I am sure IE will follow soon.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api

Here is one example that should be helpful for your case and supports all browsers:
http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound